# Updating IP address in config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, app-config

Newbie question here, I am trying to change the IP address of our database server. In our config.cs we have:

```
public class Config
{
    private const string DevelopmentIp = "127.0.0.1";
    private const string ProductionIp = "199.199.199.199";
```

But on the live server we only have the compiled site. Is it possible to change the IP address without having to recompile the entire application? Is it possible to manually edit the live site with the new IP address?

Comment: Network expert guy can switch the IP of server, but the domain mapping takes time,  lets say example.com mapped to 192.... and later changed ip to 168.9.0.0, then exmple.com mapping to 168.9.0.0 will take time to reflect. But as a suggestion, you should keep this type of thing in `config`.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Are you using the ancient ASP (pre .NET)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Classic ASP is a scripting language and doesn't have strongly typed variables, so they must be using ASP.Net not Classic ASP.

Comment: @Lankymart: yeah, I know that. I'm trying to get the OP to decide he used the wrong tag.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Subtlety doesn't work well on SO in my experience, anyway edited the tags now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never keep **ConnectionString** in your source code.

Instead, you want to keep **ConnectionString** in **web.config**. If you worry about hacking web.config , then you can decrypt it using **aspnet_regiis.exe** *(which is not your original question)*.

> But on the live server we only have the compiled site. Is it possible
>   to change the IP address without having to recompile the entire
>   application? Is it possible to manually edit the live site with the
>   new IP address?

**Answer is No**. You have hard-coded IP address inside **config.cs**. You need to update it, and re-compile the application.

Comment: In other words, keep this sort of thing out of source, and always put it in a config file.

Comment: Also consider "Config Transforms" which would alleviate the need for storing two separate values for development and production.